# How to get name of tab in Facebook C# SDK

Tags: tabs, facebook-c#-sdk

I have created canvas app and displayed it in iFrame on facebook Tab.
I want to read name of the Page tab i am currently inside, is it possible to get name of the tab, either via signed request or C# sdk?

Best Regards
Imran.